# using awk to print lines from one match through a second instance of a separate match

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have one requirement. Let’s say my file contents are

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
d
e
f
```

I want to print the lines from `b` to 2nd time repeated `d`. Is there any command using awk to do this?

Output should be

```
b
c
d
e
f
d
```

If it is first time `b`, I know the command

```
awk '/b/,/d/' file.txt
```

But I want to print the text to the matching point if it repeats second time.
I want to have the command with in one line.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use flags and counter to keep track

```
$ awk '/b/{f=1; c=0} f; /d/ && ++c==2{f=0}' file.txt
b
c
d
e
f
d
```

- `/b/{f=1; c=0}` set flag for starting match and initialize counter
- `f;` print input record as long flag is set
- `/d/ && ++c==2{f=0}` clear the flag if ending string is matched for second time
- can simplify to `awk '/b/{f=1} f; /d/ && ++c==2{exit}'` if there is only one set to be extracted

Note that if ending match doesn't have 2 matches, it will print until end of input

```
$ seq 10 | awk '/4/{f=1; c=0} f; /6/ && ++c==2{f=0}'
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: You could also let `f` double as the counter, e.g.: `/b/ { f=2 } f; /d/ { f-- }`

Comment: @Thor good idea, but need `/d/ && f{ f-- }` as negative numbers evaluate as true

Answer (score 1):

1. A more readable code. Keep track of the counts of characters.
2. Print as long as count of b=1 and d<=2.
3. Stop once count of d has reached 2.

   ```
   awk '{ a[$1]++;
       if(a["b"]==1 && a["d"]<=2){
           print;
       }
       if(a["d"]==2){
          a["d"]=10
       }
   }' file.txt
   ```